# Getting issue to uninstall ebizmarts/MailChimp module

Tags: magento2.3, module, mailchimp

I try to remove Ebizmarts/MailChimp extension using the "composer remove Ebizmarts/MailChimp"
this module install using composer through but getting issues at a time to uninstall can you please suggest in solution to solve these issues
these error show in terminal

```
"ebizmarts/mailchimp is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
Package "ebizmarts/mailchimp" listed for the update is not installed. Ignoring."
```

Magento version 2.3.3

Comment: If you install it via composer you should have information in composer.json about it. Are you sure it is installed using composer?

Comment: Yes these installation via composer.

Comment: Does it get removed when performing a composer update? If not you could try and remove ebizmarts within the composer.lock file and doing another composer update

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall the module, you should be using the Magento module uninstall command instead.

`bin/magento module:uninstall Module_Name`

Comment: Yes I also try bin/magento module:uninstall Module_Name but getting msg on terminal like "package composer not found"